# Angular CLI generating component in wrong directory

Tags: angular, path, components, angular-cli

I've been using Angular-CLI for quite a while now without any problems.

However a strange issue has just developed on one of my projects.

I cd into a directory (e.g. app/some-module) and execute

```
ng g component new-component
```

I would expect cli to create a new directory inside the some-model directory, i.e.:

```
app/some-module/new-component/
```

With the component files in that directory. This is the way it has been happening every since I started with Angular CLI.

However, a couple of days ago, it stopped working. Now it will create a new directory within the app directory, i.e.

```
app/new-component/
```

I transferred the whole app (via git) to another dev machine and it works fine.

I tried in another cli project on my dev machine and it works there too.

It is just this project on my machine.

So the problem has to be in a config file in my project that is ignored by git, but I have gone through everything I can think of and can't find anything.

I also updated cli to latest (1.0.0) yesterday but this did not fix the problem.

Comment: Post your .angular-cli.json file please.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks Ahmed, you pointed me in the right direction.

I was going to post my angular.cli.json file but I thought I would have one more look at it first.

The solution turned out to involve going back to the angular-cli docs and following EVERY step in the [1.0 Upgrade Guide](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-1.0-update).

I don't know exactly which step solved the problem unfortunately because nothing worked until I restarted my Terminal session. Then everything was OK.

But the only things I did were the steps in the upgrade guide.